# Any way to MD5 hash a string within WiX?

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, md5

I have been googling and read through the WiX tutorial (http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/), but I am unable to see a simple way to create an MD5 hash of a string/property.  Does anyone know of any built in WiX Installer methods to do this or is my only option a custom action?

I am currently using WiX version 3.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing in WiX or MSI to hash a string.

Comment: Do you know of a good way to achieve this?  Just create a custom action dll?

Comment: Yes, you need custom code for this. If it's a custom action or some EXE which modifies the installer depends on what you need to do with the hash.

Comment: Also realize that if you end up using .NET for your custom action that MD5 is not FIPS compliant and can throw an exception if a policy setting is enabled to enforce compliance.  Use something else like SHA.

Comment: Sorry, it was actually a SHA1 hash i was trying to do.  I had to create a .NET DLL to accomplish this.